# Is $g:R^2\to R:(x,y)\mapsto xy$ a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

> In English:
>
> Denoting by $ G $ and $ U $ as the linear transformation and the vector space, respectively, we have: $\\$ First, check if the zero vector $0=(0,0)\in U$ is also present in the linear transformation $G$: $$0=(0,0)\Longrightarrow G(0,0)=0\cdot0$$ Verified.$$$$
>
> Second, we find the sum. $\\$
> Given two vectors any vector space in question $$u_1=(x_1,y_1)$$$$u_2=(x_2,y_2)$$ Making the sum of both vectors we obtain $$u_1+u_2=(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$$ Making $G(u+v)$ we have: $$G(u+v)=G(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)$$
> $$=x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$$
> $$=G(u)+G(v)+x_1y_2+x_2y_1$$
> Not Verified. $$\\$$
> Logo $G$ is not linear transformation. Correct?

Em português:
Denotando de $G$ e $U$ como sendo a transformação linear e o espaço vetorial, respectivamente, temos:$\\$Primeiro, verificamos se o vetor nulo $0=(0,0)\in U$ também está presente na transformação linear $G$: $$0=(0,0)\Longrightarrow G(0,0)=0\cdot0=0$$Verificado.$$$$
Segundo, verificamos a soma.$\\$
Dados dois vetores quaisquer do espaço vetorial em questão $$u_1=(x_1,y_1)$$ $$u_2=(x_2,y_2)$$Fazendo a soma de ambos os vetores obtemos $$u_1+u_2=(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)=(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)$$ Fazendo a $G(u+v)$ temos: $$G(u+v)=G(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=(x_1+x_2)(y_1+y_2)$$
$$=x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_2y_1+x_2y_2$$
$$=G(u)+G(v)+x_1y_2+x_2y_1$$
Não Verificado.$$\\$$
Logo $G$ não é transformação Linear.$$\\$$

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is a bilinear transformation.

Comment: Novikiv But is transformation linear?

Comment: No, it isn't, you had proved this.